# Getting the apartment cleaning and dish washing to work properly with Omega Theme?

Tags: theming

I have enabled the setting under themes for the option, "It also helps you to clean your appartment and wash your dishes." Although double and triple checked, there appears to be no change.

I looked through the code to see if there was anything I could fix but unfortunately I'm a little light on my life-theming capabilities. I haven't yet been able to integrate Drupal with reality as of yet.

Am I missing an extra setting or is this a known bug?

Comment: Did you clear the cache on your Roomba?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check settings for filth and grime under settings.php, these settings override any other setting in omega be sure they are both are set to active. Run update.php.

It's possible that your filth and grime settings are set too low so you may need to adjust these in your ini.php file. (i have mine set to "CDC alert")

Any use of hand-sanitizer or disinfecting sprays can cause the omega settings to malfunction, this is a known issue.

Comment: Maybe some heavy drushing? ...in other news, I'm honored this question was enough motivation for you to sign up for an account here. You seem to know what you're talking about so welcome. Now get to answering some real questions! lol